# Flutter: Flexible failing when wrapped with column

Tags: flutter, user-interface, flexbox, frontend, styles

I have the current text bubble widget that displays basic information. Its build using containers and such, and looks like the following:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final messageTextGroup = Flexible(
        child: Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(14),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.grey[900],
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: Radius.circular(18),
              bottomLeft: Radius.circular(18),
              bottomRight: Radius.circular(18),
            ),
          ),
          child: Text(
            message.message,
            style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white, fontFamily: 'Monstserrat', fontSize: 14),
          ),
        ),
        CustomPaint(painter: Triangle(Colors.grey[900])),
      ],
    ));

    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 18.0, left: 50, top: 5, bottom: 5),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        children: <Widget>[
          SizedBox(height: 30),
          messageTextGroup,
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

That looks like this:
[image]

I want to add text under it. However, when i wrap the flexible in a column,

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final messageTextGroup = Column(
      children: [
        Flexible(
            child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(14),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.grey[900],
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(18),
                  bottomLeft: Radius.circular(18),
                  bottomRight: Radius.circular(18),
                ),
              ),
              child: Text(
                message.message,
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontFamily: 'Monstserrat',
                    fontSize: 14),
              ),
            ),
            CustomPaint(painter: Triangle(Colors.grey[900])),
          ],
        )),
        //timeago text
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 8.0),
          child: Text(
            timeago.format(message.dateTime),
            style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.grey[600],
                fontFamily: 'Monstserrat',
                fontSize: 10),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
```

It becomes completely invisible, and the messages are no longer on the screen. Any know whats going on? Thanks!

Comment: Can you include full sample widget from scaffold that will reproduce the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Try by replacing **Flexible** with **IntrinsicHeight**